# Double while loop works in one page, but not in second page

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a release of a website. On the homepage all the newest releases are shown from the different apps. Then for every app you have a seperate page where you can find all the released versions

I need to get results out of a database, for this I use a while loop (one while loop for 32 bit, one for 64 bit). When I use it on the homepage, it works just how it's supposed to. Gives exactly the result I want from the query.

But when I use it on the second page the 32 bit while loop gives all the results double. But only if there is the same version number from the 64 bit. The 64 bit while loop works just fine.

Here is a bit of the code (there will be some mistakes in it but im working on those, such as same id's and all) I also know this probably isn't the best approach but it works on the homepage, so I actually want it just like this

```
                <div class="content">
                <div class="content-1">
                        <?php

                    $page = $_GET["pageid"];                            
                        echo "<p class='intro'>Download here the ".$page." final releases</p>";


                    echo "<h3>".$page."</h3>";

                        require("Function/query.php");

            $queryapp = $amx32;
                $queryapp_result = mysql_query($queryapp);


                    while ($queryapprow = mysql_fetch_array($queryapp_result))
                    {
                        $queryapp64 = $amx64;
                        $queryapp64_result = mysql_query($queryapp64);
                        while ($queryapprow64 = mysql_fetch_array($queryapp64_result))
                            {   

                echo "<div class='amxrow' style='opacity:1;'>       
                        <p class='tables'>
                        <table class='table1'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope='row' id='bit32'>32 Bit</th>
                                <th scope='row' id='bit64'>64 Bit</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>        
                            <tbody>

                                <tr>

                                    <th scope='row'>Version</th>
                                    <td class='version'>".$queryapprow['Version']."</td>
                                    <td class='version64'>".$queryapprow64['Version']."</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope='row'>Released</th>
                                    <td class='datum'>".$queryapprow['Released']."</td>
                                    <td class='datum64'>".$queryapprow64['Released']."</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope='row'>Build by</th>
                                    <td>".$queryapprow['BuilBy']."</td>
                                    <td>".$queryapprow64['BuilBy']."</td>
                                </tr>   

                            </tbody>    
                        </table>
                        </p>
<div class='panelnotes'>


            <div style='clear:both;'></div>
                <div class='columnsnotes'>
                    <div class='colleftnotes'>
                    ".nl2br($queryapprow['Notes'])." 
                    </div>
                </div>       
                        <div style='clear:both;'></div>

            </div>

            <div class='triggernotes' style='opacity:1;'>Release   Notes</div>
            <a href='http://localhost/ReleaseWebsite/".$queryapprow['path']."'><div class='download32' style='opacity:1;'>Download redhat_e5 32bit</div></a>
                        <a href='http://localhost/ReleaseWebsite/".$queryapprow64['path']."'><div class='download64' style='opacity:1;'>Download redhat_e5 64bit</div></a>



                            <hr noshade id='line1'>
                            </div>";


            }       
            }

                            ?>
```

Anyone an idea?

*EDIT*
Here are the two queries:

```
$amx32 = "SELECT * FROM $page WHERE Type='Final' AND architecture= '32bit' ORDER BY  Version DESC";
$amx64 = "SELECT * FROM $page WHERE Type='Final' AND architecture= '64bit' ORDER BY Version DESC";
```

@Mr.alien the $page has the nothing to do with it. it only gives wich application table it will be chosen from

Comment: I think you should show us that SQL query or queries.

Comment: check the value of `$_GET['page_id']`, It might be same

Answer (score 0):

better separate your loop for 32bit and 64bit, because of the nested loop that may cause your program loop it twice.

example:

//loop for 32 bit

while(){

}
//loop for 64 bit

while(){

}

Comment: i am now trying that. but then i face the problem that i cannot get the 2 seperate while loops in one table..

Comment: Try only one query which sort by version DESC... anyways you have theme in the same table...that would also minimize your code..

Comment: but when i order by version than the 32bit and 64 bit wouldn't be seperate right?